# Azure Cosmos DB multitenancy Java SDK

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are currently looking into best practices concerning Cosmos DB and its Java SDK in combination with multitenancy. We have a simple Spring Boot based Java service that is providing REST interfaces for CRUD operations on data in a Cosmos DB using the SQL API. Now we need to introduce multitenancy into it. The tenant classifier will be read from a JWT when receiving a REST request and be available in the requests Thread Local context.

Current considerations are to have the data of one tenant in either a separate container or a separate database under one database account. As described in the MS document [Multitenancy and Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/service/cosmos-db).

Having all data in one container using the tenant classifier as a partition key will not work due to the amount of data, plus we need separation of the data to prevent the noisy neighbour problem.

Are there any best practices on how to design the data access layer - also in regards of performance pitfalls?

Our understanding at the moment

- Use one CosmosDBClient per application (as the initialization takes time)
- Container names are defined on entity level (@Container())

The official sample create individual repositories and database configs [Azure Spring Boot Cosmos Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/spring-cloud-azure_4.0.0/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos/cosmos-multi-database-single-account/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/cosmos/multi/database/MultiDatabaseApplication.java) which sounds wrong to me

Basically

- Should we create on CosmosDB client and dynamically (how?) set the container name or database name before executing a CRUD operation?
- Should we create separate clients for every tenant and re-use those instances?

Answer (score 0):

How to design the data layer for multi-tenant apps in Azure Cosmos DB will depend on the level of tenant density you want at both the application tier and the database tier. There is no one-fits-all "best practice", as this will be a value judgement/trade-off between cost of tenant resources and performance.

It seems from your question that your preference is to have high tenant density at the application tier (i.e. be able to reference and/or create many tenant resources from a single application instance), while keeping performance isolation at the database tier (to avoid the "noisy neighbour" problem).

To answer the question of how to dynamically set the container name or database name before executing a CRUD operation: from version **3.33.0** of the Spring Data Client Library for Azure Cosmos DB, you can now make your Spring Data Repository code dynamically reference and/or create different databases or containers in Azure Cosmos DB for each tenant, from the same application instance and the same client. To achieve this at database level, create a class which extends CosmosFactory:

```
public class MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory extends CosmosFactory {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory .class);
    private CosmosAsyncClient client;
    public String tenantId;

    public MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory (CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient, String databaseName) {
        super(cosmosAsyncClient, databaseName);
        this.client = cosmosAsyncClient;
        this.tenantId = databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        //have some logic here that will determine the tenant id in the current thread
        //so you can set this.tenantId to be the current tenant
        return this.tenantId;
    }
}
```

Then, in your configuration class, add your new MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory class as a bean:

```
@Bean 
 public MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory cosmosFactory(CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient) {
    return new MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory (cosmosAsyncClient, getDatabaseName());
 }
```

The overridden `getDatabaseName()` will then be invoked polymorphically by every CRUD method you call on Spring Data `Repository`, so you will need to add some logic that will determine the tenant id in the current thread, and set that value to be returned. To do the same at container level instead, you would just override the `overrideContainerName()` method in CosmosFactory instead, and add similar logic.

I've written a blog, which goes into more detail on this, and has links to extended samples. You can find the blog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/building-multi-tenant-java-apps-using-spring-data-and-azure-cosmos-db/).